# "RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied" Only when testing single images with the same input size. pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I trained a pytorch model on datapoints of 64x64x3 and it did the training and evaluation fine.
when I tried to test the same model on live images I run into this error even though the input size **is the same**.

model:

```
class liveClassifier(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(liveClassifier, self).__init__()
    # input: 64x64x3
    self.conv01 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=8, kernel_size=3)
    # => 62x62x8
    self.conv02 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)
    # => 60x60x16
    self.pool01 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
    # => 30x30x16
    self.conv03 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
    # => 28x28x32
    self.pool02 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
    # => 14x14x32
    self.conv04 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
    # => 12x12x64
    self.pool03 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
    # => 6x6x64
    self.linear01 = nn.Linear(6 * 6 * 64, 32)
    self.linear02 = nn.Linear(32, 16)
    self.linear03 = nn.Linear(16, 3)

  def forward(self, input):
    x = self.conv01(input)
    x = F.relu(x)
    
    x = self.conv02(x)
    x = F.relu(x)

    x = self.pool01(x)

    x = self.conv03(x)
    x = F.relu(x)

    x = self.pool02(x)

    x = self.conv04(x)
    x = F.relu(x)

    x = self.pool03(x)

    x = x.flatten(start_dim=1) # ??
    
    x = self.linear01(x)
    x = F.relu(x)

    x = self.linear02(x)
    x = F.relu(x)

    x = self.linear03(x)
    
    output = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
    return output
```

this code is the tarining that worked fine

```
num_epochs = 30

train_loss_list = []
train_acc_list = []

validation_loss_list = []
validation_acc_list = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  
  train_running_loss = 0.0
  train_acc = 0.0

  model = model.train()

  for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        ## forward + backprop + loss
        logits = model(images)
        loss = criterion(logits, labels)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        ## update model params
        optimizer.step()

        train_running_loss += loss.detach().item()
        train_acc += get_accuracy(logits, labels, BATCH_SIZE)
    

  
  model = model.eval()
  validation_running_loss = 0.0
  validation_acc = 0.0
  for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(validation_loader, 0):
    images = images.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(device)
    outputs = model(images)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    validation_running_loss += loss.detach().item()
    validation_acc += get_accuracy(outputs, labels, BATCH_SIZE)
  
  train_loss_list.append(train_running_loss / i)
  train_acc_list.append(train_acc / i)
  validation_loss_list.append(validation_running_loss / i)
  validation_acc_list.append(validation_acc / i)
  
  print('Epoch: %d | Train Loss: %.4f | Train Accuracy: %.2f' \
          %(epoch, train_running_loss / i, train_acc / i))
  print('Validation Loss: %.4f | Validation Accuracy: %.2f' \
          %(validation_running_loss / i, validation_acc / i))


model = model.eval()
```

this classification did not work due to this error

```
print(type(frame))
frame = transform(Image.fromarray(frame)).float().to(device)
print(frame.shape) # torch.Size([3, 64, 64])
model.eval()
print(model(frame))
```

When I checked the data tensor shapes I got 64x64x3 in both cases, therefore I have no idea why one would work and the other won't.

Comment: The input tensor is often expected to have shape `(1, 3, 64, 64)`. The `1` is then a remnant of the fact that you trained your model in batches, i.e.  a batch has shape `(batch_size, 3, 64, 64)`. You could do `expand_dims(axis=0)` using numpy, or use a torch equivalent. Check the shape of your batch (`images` in the loop) to confirm the shape, not an individual training image.

Comment: thank you, you were right! TheEngineerProgrammer blow commented the rest of the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just unsqueeze the the image to get [1, 3, 64, 64]. In pytorch you can do that with `frame.unsqueeze(0)`